# replace text string with span using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I find the string and wrap it into span using jQuery? For example,

```
<p>
  <span class="span1">afijaifjiaj</span>
  ajfijaogoag
  <span class="span1">afijaifjiaj</span>
  aokaodgg
  <span class="span1">afijaifjiaj</span>
</p>
```

I want to make it as:

```
<p>
  <span class="span1">afijaifjiaj</span>
  <span class="span2">ajfijaogoag</span>
  <span class="span1">afijaifjiaj</span>
  <span class="span2">aokaodgg</span>
  <span class="span1">afijaifjiaj</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Try using this selector:    $('*:contains("I am a simple string")');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/3nxjk/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/3nxjk/3/

`nodeType` - 3  Represents textual content in an element or attribute.

and `$(this).text().trim()` trims white space and checks the valid string.

Rest should fit your need `:)`

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("p").contents().filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType === 3 && $(this).text().trim() != "";
    }).wrap('<span class="span2">');

    alert($('p').html());
});
```

Comment: what is `nodeType === 3` mean?

Comment: @Dvir **check this out** : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FNode.nodeType `:)` The nodeType property returns the node type, as a number, of the specified node.

Comment: Depending on cross-browser requirements, it might be worth using [`$.trim($(this).text())`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) rather than using `String.trim()` ([it's unsupported in IE < 9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know jQuery, so here's a way with pure JavaScript:

```
var stringToReplace='randomtext';
dpcument.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace(stringToReplace,'<span>'+stringToReplace+'</span>');
```